# Unable to save a data.frame after using group_by and summarise functions in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

```
data_different_tech_count <- data_different_tech %>% 
                                 group_by(tech) %>% 
                                 summarise(count(tech))
```

now this gives me a data.frame as an output but I am unable to save the file. When I try to change the colnames, it shows me:

```
colnames(data1)[c(1,2)]<- c("tech","count")
```

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("tech", "count")) : 
>     'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

When I am using

```
colnames(data_different_count_tech)
```

It says that I have only one column.
When I am using the

```
summary(data_different_count_tech)
```

it shows two columns.

When I am trying to write this file to my directory it returns the following error.

```
write.csv(file=data_different_tech_count,"tech.csv")
```

> Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Comment: I think you need `summarise (count = n ())`. But you haven't named the variable you've created, and I'm not sure how dplyr will handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a count of the number of times each value of `tech` appears? I can't get your example to work without having a reproducible example.

If so, here are a few alternatives that will give you what you want:

## Using Dplyr

```
data_different_tech_count <- data_different_tech %>% group_by(tech) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

## Using Base R

```
data_different_tech_count <- as.data.frame(table(data_different_tech$tech)) 
colnames(data_different_tech_count) <- c("tech","count")
```

Comment: Hi Michael Gao, Yes I have a data.frame with one column. It has factors and some are repeating. Now I need the count of each factor in another column. The above code which you have sent me is also throwing me an error saying Error in n() : This function should not be called directly

Comment: The above answers are correct but Basically Dependency issues with dplyr and plyr. detach plyr and run , it is working.